# How to find nodes fast in an unordered tree

Tags: algorithm, tree-traversal

I have an unordered tree in the form of, for example:

```
Root
    A1
        A1_1
            A1_1_1
            A1_1_2
                    A1_1_2_1
                    A1_1_2_2
                    A1_1_2_3
            A1_1_3
            A1_1_n
        A1_2
        A1_3
        A1_n
    A2
        A2_1
        A2_2
        A2_3
        A2_n
```

- The tree is unordered
- each child can have a random N count of children
- each node stores an unique long value.
- the value required can be at any position.

My problem: if I need the long value of **A1_1_2_3**, first time I will traverse the nodes I do depth first search to get it, however: on later calls to the same node I must get its value without a recursive search. Why? If this tree would have hundreds of thousands of nodes until it reaches my A1_1_2_3 node, it would take too much time. 
What I thought of, is to leave some pointers after the first traverse. E.g. for my case, when I give back the long value for A1_1_2_3 I also give back an array with information for future searches of the same node and say: to get to A1_1_2_3, I need:

- first child of Root, which is A1
- first child of A1, which is A1_1
- second child of A1_1, which is A1_1_2
- third child of A1_1_2, which is what I need: A1_1_2_3

So I figured I would store this information along with the value for A1_1_2_3 as an array of indexes: [0, 0, 1, 2]. By doing so, I could easily recreate the node on subsequent calls to the A1_1_2_3 and avoid recursion each time.

However the nodes can change. On subsequent calls, I might have a new structure, so my indexes stored earlier would not match anymore. But if this happens, I thought whnever I dont find the element anymore, I would recursively go back up a level and search for the item, and so on until I find it again and store the indexes again for future references:

e.g. if my A1_1_2_3 is now situated in this new structure:

```
    A1_1
        A1_1_0
        A1_1_1
        A1_1_2
                A1_1_2_1
                A1_1_2_2
                A1_1_21_22
                A1_1_2_3
```

... in this case the new element A1_1_0 ruined my stored structure, so I would go back up a level and search children again recursively until I find it again.

Does this even make sense, what I thought of here, or am I overcomplicating things? Im talking about an unordered tree which can have max about three hundreds of thousands of nodes, and it is vital that I can jump to nodes as fast as possible. But the tree can also be very small, under 10 nodes.

Is there a more efficient way to search in such a situation?

Thank you for any idea.

---

edit:

I forgot to add: what I need on subsequent calls is not just the same value, but also its position is important, because I must get the next page of children after that child (since its a tree structure, Im calling paging on nodes after the initially selected one). Hope it makes more sense now.

Comment: Unfortunately your idea didn't make sense (to me anyway). Simply use a cache (between key and node, not node path)

Comment: ah ok, i see what you mean. My problem is that I need not just the value of the node itself, (so I cant just cache that and be done) but the position too , because on subsequent calls I need the next page of children after the node). I should have specified this info in the OP

Comment: Yeah, you need to elaborate on something: Your explanation suggests that A1_1_2_3, say, is a key in the sense that you know that it's a child node of A1_1_2. But then, if the tree structure changes, how do you identify the node you are looking for (or its parent, and so on)?

Comment: Do you have any control over the creation of the tree? If you have control, then using an ordered structure will be a cleaner solution. For the data, what's the common case? If it's 10 elements, the search probably doesn't matter. Aim for better data structures and then only optimize if it matters.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError true, very good point. Did not think of that.

Comment: I agree with you, the way the tree is stored is far from optimal.  I do not have the option to order the tree, because the parent/child relation must be kept as is (think replies and comments to replies, if I order them by date or something to make it easier on the search, I lose the initial structure). About the data itself, its random; I can have anywhere from a few items of items to hundreds of thousands. This is another thing that makes it difficult for me to select a fitting search algorithm

Comment: What is the difference from searching an unordered list?

Comment: Could you post some code showing your tree structure and the operations?